# storing the value in the variable

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to use jquery GET functionality to load the value from the external page to a variable

```
var cbname = $.get('/getname.php','name='+item.f);
alert(cbname);
```

but in alert it is bringing me an `object object`

Can anyone guide what is the best approach to do this:

Comment: it returns a promise object

Comment: try console.debug(cbname) to see what it contains

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958282/how-do-i-load-html-into-a-variable-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
var cbname;

$.get('/getname.php','name='+item.f, function(data) {
    cbname = data;
    alert(cbname);
});
```

Gotta use the success callback.

If you don't want to use the callback, but instead want a synchronous call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
     url:    '/getname.php?name='+item.f,
     success: function(data) {
         cbname = data;
     },
      async:   false
});

alert(cbname);
```

Also note that if item.f is not url safe, you'll want to use

```
'/getname.php?name='+encodeURIComponent(item.f)
```

instead

Comment: Pretty sure you are going to get `undefined` from this. `alert` also needs to be in the callback.

Comment: guys, if i use above and place the alert outside the callback, it gives me `object object`, How do i use it outside..

Comment: updated for synchronous feature (SJAX instead of AJAX)

Answer (score 0):

If you are making web requests, don't take the easy way out by forcing your program to run synchronously, instead start to think like an AJAX programmer: instead of thinking "I need a function that returns a value," an AJAX programmer thinks, "I need a function that does something with a value once I have it."

You want something like the following:

```
$.get('/getname.php','name=' + item.f, myCallback);

function myCallback(cbname) {
    alert(cbname);
}
```