# How to load data into variable instead selector in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, variables, load, selector

I am having some trouble to load data from url with load method in jQuery into variable instead selector.

So my code is this:

```
$('#test').load('http://url #searchedID');
```

So this would load some string from url where html selector have id = searchedID e.g. "This is string" and then it would display this string into html selector where id = test.

**My question is:** How to load data in my case (from: #searchedID) instead into selector where id = test into **variable**. Something like this:

```
var loadHereData = load('url, #searchedID');
```

But this is not corect!

Realy thanks for any advice.

Comment: so essentially you want to copy content from #searchID to another div or something ?

Comment: no, just put/get in variable e.g. "var load" so i can in this page do something else, like parse etc, basicly I do not whant to display it, just load it or get it...

Comment: use `$.get` as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958282/how-do-i-load-html-into-a-variable-with-jquery

Comment: hmm @DhirajBodicherla this is more likly, do you think this would work: $.get("url #searchedID", function( my_var ) {}, 'html');

Comment: no it won't work, in this case "my_var" is whole html from url, how to get that specific data from selector where id = searchedID?

Comment: how about someting like this http://jsbin.com/jujotafamo/1/edit?html,js,output

you load the page and search in the page what you want and store it in your variable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `$.get` the page and search for the required element and store it like this

```
var myContent;
$.get("http://jsbin.com/ficoniniwo/1.html", function(data) {
  var tempData = $('<output>').append($.parseHTML(data)).find('h1');
  myContent = tempData.html();
}, 'text');
```

Here is a [Demo](http://jsbin.com/weveni/1/edit?html,js,output)

The html received from 1.html is converted to a jquery object by [`$.parsehtml`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) and then I'm appending it so that I can search in it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i see a problem with my answer. Please hold on

Comment: why is returning as result [object Object]?

Comment: I think i messed up something. Sorry about that. I'm working on it now.

Comment: updated my answer. Please check now and let me know if it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery load method places the downloaded HTML into a matched element.  If you want to store the contents of #searchedID in a variable, you can first create a variable containing an empty jQuery DOM element.

```
var loadHereData = $("<div id='test'></div>");
loadHereData.Load('url #searchedID');
```

The loadHereData variable will now contain a div holding the contents of the #searchedID element.

Comment: also here result of loadHereData is [object Object]