# How to read external html file and store it to string variable using jQuery? Showing Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, dynamic-programming

I am trying to Dynamically Generating the Codes for Web Application
I Want to read **External HTML File** and store it to string variable in Javascript or Jquery ?
Is there any efficient way for this..?

HTML File -
*Object-text.html*

```
<div class="text-object">
    <div class='text-area'>
        <span class='content'>
            <span class='title'> title</span><br/>
            <span class='address'>  address  </span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class='patch'></div>
</div>
<br class='float-clear'/>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.get("templates/object-text.html", function(html_string)
   {
      alert(html_string);  // this is not Working
   });
});
```

**Showing Error in Console**

Junk After Docuement Element

awaiting responses.
 
*Thanks in Advance*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I load html into a variable with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958282/how-do-i-load-html-into-a-variable-with-jquery)

Comment: @mariusz thank you my purpose similarly same as you shared, but its doesn't works

Comment: Are the contents of the HTML file okay? Can you check the *Network* tab in the developer tools and inspect the *Response* tab of the XHR request to see if the file isn't mangled? Assuming *Junk after document element* is the error message you are getting, maybe XHR isn't the issue here, instead jQuery maybe tries parsing XML and fails? Check https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ `dataType` default is intelligent guess, try setting it to `string`.

Comment: @Tomáš Hübelbauer Thank you i will try that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Changed JQUERY Code**

i've added the extra arguement to the function call $.get() to specify the html content

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.get("templates/object-text.html", function(html_string)
   {
      alert(html_string); 
   },'html');    // this is the change now its working
});
```

Comment: Today 3 Dec 2022 and it works. you saved me a big trobule.

Answer (score 1):

```
this verion is working fine for me you have to close `);` 
$(document).ready(function()
    {
      $.get("leads/leads_custom_box.php", function(result)
       {
          alert(result);
       });
    });
```

Comment: just add a closing bracket for $.get( ); it will work

Comment: What you getting the output..? HTML Code or what else..?

Comment: i already closed that in my local file.. i am getting object XMLDocument

Comment: what is in your file you want to include what content it posses

Comment: $(document).ready(function()
    {
      $.get("templates/epc-object-text.html", function(result)
       {
          alert(result);
       });
    });

Comment: copy and pest exact lines and see

Comment: Now it is workings, need to add another arguement, to specify the html content, i will add that  in answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121413/discussion-between-amit-kumar-pawar-and-keerthi-vasan).

Answer (score 1):

using jquery

```
$.get("http://localhost/something/something.html", function (result) {
     html = result;
     text = $(result).text();
});
```