# How do I set the contents of a javascript variable to the contents of a text file?

Tags: javascript

I have two javascript variables each set to a text string of html code in the following example (see var organization and var person below).  How would I instead set those variables to content of text files (so I could put the html code in text files instead)?

```
<script>
function showtab(tabs) {
  var tab = tabs;
  var organization = "<div><label>Organization:</label><input type='text' name='org' value='' /></div>";
  var person = "<div><label>First Name:</label><input type='text' name='per_first' value='' /></div><div><label>Middle Name:</label><input type='text' name='per_middle' value='' /></div><div><label>Last Name:</label><input type='text' name='per_last' value='' /></div>";
  switch (tab) 
  {
    case "tab-1":
      // Set tab-1 to variable organization when clicking on tab-1
      document.getElementById('tab-container').innerHTML = organization;
      document.getElementById("tab-a").style.backgroundColor = "#bababb"; // Light Grey
      document.getElementById("tab-b").style.backgroundColor = "#dddddd"; // Dark Grey
      break;
    case "tab-2":
      // Set tab-2 to variable person when clicking on tab-2
      document.getElementById('tab-container').innerHTML = person;
      document.getElementById("tab-a").style.backgroundColor = "#dddddd"; // Dark Grey
      document.getElementById("tab-b").style.backgroundColor = "#bababb"; // Light Grey
      break;
    default:
      document.getElementById('tab-container').innerHTML = document.getElementById("tab-1").innerHTML;
      break;
  }
}
</script>
```

```
<form method='post' action=''>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Create Contact</legend>
    <div id='nav'>
      <div id='tab-a' class='tab'>
        <a href="javascript:showtab('tab-1')">Organization</a>
      </div>
      <div id='tab-b' class='tab'>
        <a href="javascript:showtab('tab-2')">Person</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id='tabbed-content'>
      <div id='tab-container'>
        <div>
          <label>Organization:</label>
          <input type='text' name='org' value='' />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id='tab-1' style='visibility:hidden; display:none;'>
      </div>
      <div id='tab-2' style='visibility:hidden; display:none;'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='form-actions'>
      <div class='form-submit'>
        <input type='submit' name='popup-x' value='CREATE' />
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Store in a JSON file and search how to use `fetch`

Comment: Your might be looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051658/how-to-read-external-html-file-and-store-it-to-string-variable-using-jquery-sho have a look