# Getting Text From Fetch Response Object

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch-api

I'm using `fetch` to make API calls and everything works but in this particular instance I'm running into an issue because the API simply returns a string -- not an object.

Typically, the API returns an object and I can parse the JSON object and get what I want but in this case, I'm having trouble finding the text I'm getting from the API in the response object.

Here's what the response object looks like.
[image]

I thought I'd find the text inside the body but I can't seem to find it. Where do I look?

Comment: You can use `typeof` to check the type returned, if object then something and if string then something else.

Comment: OK but where's the actual text response in the response object? After the typeof check, I'll still have to extract the string that I'm expecting from the response.

Comment: Use .text() method to read the response stream.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Using the fetch JavaScript API you can try:

```
response.text().then(function (text) {
  // do something with the text response 
});
```

Also take a look at the docs on [**fetch** > **response** > **body interface methods**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#Body_Interface_Methods)

Answer (score 48):

ES6 Syntax:

```
fetch("URL")
   .then(response => response.text())
   .then((response) => {
       console.log(response)
   })
   .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: Why is there then two-times?

Comment: because response.text() returns promise

Comment: Though this works, I'd stick with the MDN pattern (second `then` chained to `response.text()` ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text)).

Comment: @thdoan do you mind explaining why? is it not the same thing?

Answer (score 14):

You can do this in two different ways:

1. The first option is to use the `response.text()` method, but be aware that, at Dec/2019, [its global usage is only 36.71%](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_body_text):

   ```js
   async function fetchTest() {
       let response = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/encoding/utf8');
       let responseText = await response.text();

       document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = responseText;
   }

   (async() => {
       await fetchTest();
   })();
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="result"></div>
   ```
2. The second option is to use the `response.body` property instead, which requires a little more work but has [73.94% of global usage](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_body_body):

   ```js
   async function fetchTest() {
       let response = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/encoding/utf8');
       let responseText = await getTextFromStream(response.body);
       
       document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = responseText;
   }

   async function getTextFromStream(readableStream) {
       let reader = readableStream.getReader();
       let utf8Decoder = new TextDecoder();
       let nextChunk;
       
       let resultStr = '';
       
       while (!(nextChunk = await reader.read()).done) {
           let partialData = nextChunk.value;
           resultStr += utf8Decoder.decode(partialData);
       }
       
       return resultStr;
   }

   (async() => {
       await fetchTest();
   })();
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="result"></div>
   ```

Comment: 93.14% for `response.text()` in Jan 2021.

Comment: When do you use the second option?

Comment: Why is the % usage relevant?

Comment: The global usage links appear to be broken, or at least no longer link to valid/relevant content. Can you fix them or remove them if they aren't relevant now?