# JavaScript : Get Empty String in Post Request

Tags: javascript, string, request

**Edited** : this solution don't works ([Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946457/getting-text-from-fetch-response-object))

I have an API gave me String response as shown in image below

[image]

Now I want to creat request in javascript to save this response but it gave me empty string :

```
    fetch("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", {
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", 
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true ,
        "authority": "clientportal.webresults-nt.com",
        "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"96\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"96\"",
        "accept": "q=0.8;application/json;q=0.9",
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "user-token": "",
        "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36",
        "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Windows\"",
        "origin": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site",
        "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
        "referer": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/",
        "accept-language": "ar,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,fa;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6,ms;q=0.5,tr;q=0.4"
      }
    })
.then(response => response.text())
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

[image]

Comment: `response.text()` returns a promise, so you need to `await` or `then` it: `.then(response => response.text()).then(text => console.log(text))`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Text From Fetch Response Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946457/getting-text-from-fetch-response-object)

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your API if necessary. Can you [edit] the question to show your latest code? The response appears to be there so I can't reproduce the problem...

Comment: @ggorlen sorry it gives me empty and blank response

Comment: @ggorlen I edited the question

Comment: Thanks, your updated code looks fine to me, although I'd use `text` or `data` as the variable name in the second `then`. Are you sure the API is delivering the response? What's the status? In the first `then`, try `.then(response => console.log(response.status, response.ok))`. If they're not 200 and true then something's wrong with the request or API.

Comment: @ggorlen I added as you said and gives me : 200 true

Comment: I'm out of ideas, then, sorry. I'd have to see the actual endpoint to play with it. You're sure the request/response in your dev tools is identical to the request you're dealing with in fetch?

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks alot for your time, yes I copy the request with cURL in dev tools, Many Thanks