# Angular2: Load content of html page into a variable

Tags: html, angular, http, typescript

So I have an html page located in this path:

./Help/HelpMenu/How-To-Bake-Pies.html

I'm trying to load the contents of this html page into a variable of type string like so:

```
private _content: string = '';

this.http.get("./Help/HelpMenu/How-To-Bake-Pies.html").map((html:any) => this._content = html);
```

After the second statement is executed the **_content** variable remains empty, am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate (take a look on correct marked answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958282/how-do-i-load-html-into-a-variable-with-jquery

Comment: @MrBuggy The one you posted is done through jQuery, I'm looking to do it in Angular2 using the http library

Answer (score 2):

You need to `subscribe` to the observable otherwise it won't get executed - in other words, the HTTP call will never happen

```
this.http
.get("./Help/HelpMenu/How-To-Bake-Pies.html")
.subscribe((html:any) => this._content = html);
```

`map` does not subscribe to the observable. It is used to manipulate data. `map` returns a new observable that you can subscribe to.

Comment: I'm getting a 404 (Not Found) error now using your code which means its working but can't find the HTML page, the html page is local it's not a routed HTML page so when it tries to access it using http it uses this path: http://localhost:8080/myApp/Help/HelpMenu/HelpMenu/How-To-Bake-Pies.html do you know how to fix this?

Comment: the How-To-Bake-Pies.html page is just a local asset that will have some HTML content that I want to load dynamically into a variable of type string, think of it like a .txt file that has some content that I want to load into a variable, I believe when you use http.get it tries to map it to a non-existing URL

Comment: is there a way to load the contents of the html page Local asset into a variable of type string without having to use http.get ?

Comment: If its in the root of the assets folder you should be able to do just `this.http.get('assets/myfile.json')...`

Comment: Ok what if it's in another location, like the one I posted? How do I make it work on any location?

Comment: I tried: this.http.get('assets/myfile.json') but I still get the same 404 not found error.

Comment: @EricBergman I don't think you can access the file unless its part of your project. If it is, you can then import the file into the component file and use it without making an http request.

Comment: How do I make the file part of my project? The file is in the assets folder but I still get 404 not found errror